# Why is defining a object by decltype(lamda) not allowed and how could i improve it?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was studying `lambda` expressions and came across this question:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    auto lam = [](int a){ cout<<"a"; };
    decltype(lam) bb; // oop! deleted default constructor!
    bb(1);
}
```

But the compiler complained as commented above. As far as I know, lambda is a object of an unnamed class. So I supposes this snippet could work.

Where did I make mistakes and could I improve it? **What kind of constructor does A lambda have?** Is there any non-default constructor that I can do like `decltype(lambda) object(args...)`?

Comment: But you declared the function to take a parameter, and you didn't give it one...

Comment: classes don't have to have a default constructor

Comment: @Tas I give it in `b(1)`

Comment: @NathanOliver So what kind of constructor does lambda have?

Comment: The compiler will complain about a lot  of other things - like not  including some header files.

Comment: @M.M Because it is obviously not compilable for reasons other than the question..

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm not asking why is this not compilable,since i've give the compiler's prompt. I'm asking how could i improve this code snippet

Comment: @Great It won't compile because he doesn't include the relevant header files.If he posted code that did that, we might be able to diagnose his problem.

Comment: Don't post snippets.

Comment: FYI, this was [voted into the C++20 WD](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-albuquerque-november-2017/#cxx20) at the last meeting, [as seen here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-12).

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ok,I've modified

Comment: @chris: Almost. That's about using it in unevaluated contexts, isn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, It's below that one. I've also now linked into the current draft.

Comment: @chris: Oh yeah lol. Nice one - that goes in my answer, ta

Answer (score 6):

The fact that a lambda is implemented as a class is not really any of the programmer's concern. You are not supposed to know/care/think about that. By extension, whether it has a default constructor, or why it does/doesn't, is irrelevant to our day-to-day lives.

As it happens, it currently doesn't:

> `[C++14: expr.prim.lambda/20]:` The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has an implicitly-declared copy constructor (12.8) and may have an implicitly-declared move constructor (12.8). *[..]*
>
> `[C++17: expr.prim.lambda/11]:` The closure type associated with a lambda-expression has no default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has a defaulted copy constructor and a defaulted move constructor. *[..]*

However! This will [change in C++20](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-albuquerque-november-2017/#cxx20), as described in document [P0624r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0624r2.pdf). As far as I can tell, your code will become valid per that standard ([as long as you don't add any captures to it](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-12)).

But, for now, if you want to store functions, use `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
   std::function<void(int)> bb;
   bb = [](int a) { std::cout << a << '\n'; };
   
   // (time passes)
   bb(1);
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1dde916dd06d714))

<sub>**Disclaimer:** This is a contrived example. In the code above, you *wouldn't* take on the overhead of `std::function`; you'd just do `auto lam = ...` as in the original code and that would be that. But the OP has shown a need to copy it into a new, default-constructible object for whatever reason. That is what I show how to do.</sub>

Comment: But... OP wants to default-construct a new one, not copy it. Doing that with an `std::function` will yield an empty one, which will throw.

Comment: @Quentin: I'm not following. Can you show with code?

Comment: @Quentin I just want construct a new one by `decltype`,not necessarily a default one.

Comment: There, should be complete now.

Comment: @choxsword oh, okay, I did get stuck on that.

Comment: So is there any non-default constructor that i can do like `decltype(lambda) object(args...)` ?

Comment: @choxsword: Pretty sure lambdas are required to be copy-constructible, so `decltype(lam) bb(lam);` should work

Comment: But if you're going to do that, then just use `auto`!

Comment: @Nemo lambdas are copy- and/or move-constructible depending on what they have captured.

Answer (score 3):

It is specified in the current Standard (N4659 [expr.prim.lambda]/11):

> The closure type associated with a lambda-expression has no default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator.  It has a defaulted copy constructor and a defaulted move constructor.

So, you cannot go `decltype(lam) bb;`. You have to initialize it from another lambda, even though this particular one doesn't have any state:

```
auto bb = lam;
```

As shown by [the proposal P0624](https://wg21.link/p0624) there's no real reason for this other than that nobody thought to allow default construction of a stateless lambda yet, and it may well become possible in C++20.

Answer (score 2):

```
decltype(lam) bb;
```

You declared the variable `bb` of some type, but not initialized it. It may be imaging like a function declaration without its definition. Try below to make your code compiled

```
decltype(lam) bb = lam;
```

or

```
decltype(lam) bb(lam);
```

It is better to use `auto` instead of `decltype()`.